# How can I ensure html elements don't overlap eventhough we render them as position:absolute and with fixed height,top and left values?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have the following code.
Note: I am using Twitter Bootsrap and Font-Awesome css)

```
<div id="divPatientFormControls">
    <div style="position:absolute;word-wrap:break-word;" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left text-left has-error">
        <div class="input-group date" style="font-size:smaller;font-weight:normal;position:absolute; width: 135px;height:24px;left:190px;top:60px " id="dateDatePicker" +="" 3405="">
            <input class="form-control valid valid-dateonly" type="text" maxlength="4000" placeholder="" value="" id="3405" name="3405"> <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="error show" id="lbl_" +="" 3405="" style="left:190px;position:absolute;font-size: 11px;top:92px ">This field is required.</label>
        </div> <span style="position:absolute;color:red;left:340px;top:60px ">*</span>

    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;word-wrap:break-word;" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left text-left ">
        <label alt="DO" for="control_ControlId" style="font-size:smaller;font-weight:normal;position:absolute; width: 24px;height:16px;left:130px;top:70px ">DO</label>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;word-wrap:break-word;" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left text-left ">
        <label alt="TO" for="control_ControlId" style="font-size:smaller;font-weight:normal;position:absolute; width: 30px;height:16px;left:130px;top:100px ">TO</label>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;word-wrap:break-word;" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left text-left has-error">
        <input type="text" style="font-size:smaller;font-weight:normal;position:absolute; width: 105px;height:24px;left:190px;top:100px " required="" class="valid-timeonly" maxlength="4000" placeholder="" value="" id="3404" name="3404">
        <div>
            <label class="error show" id="lbl_" +="" 3404="" style="left:190px;position:absolute;font-size: 11px;font-weight: bold;top:124px ">This field is required.</label>
        </div> <span style="position:absolute;color:red;left:310px;top:100px ">*</span>

    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;word-wrap:break-word;" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left text-left has-error">
        <input type="text" style="font-size:smaller;font-weight:normal;position:absolute; width: 215px;height:24px;left:190px;top:150px " required="" step="0.01" maxlength="4000" placeholder="" value="" id="3191" name="3191">
        <div>
            <label class="error show" id="lbl_" +="" 3191="" style="left:190px;position:absolute;font-size:smaller;top:174px ">This field is required.</label>
        </div> <span style="position:absolute;color:red;left:420px;top:150px ">*</span>

    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;word-wrap:break-word;" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left text-left ">
        <label alt="DOT" for="control_ControlId" style="font-size:smaller;font-weight:normal;position:absolute; width: 36px;height:16px;left:130px;top:160px ">DOT</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The input fields are placed based on their left,top positioning which are coming from DB and are dynamic and I need to honor them (or at least the relative positioning between them!)
I am actually rendering the error label just below the required input fields:

```
var errorLabelStyle = "left:" + string.Concat(@control.LeftLocation, "px") + ";position:absolute;font-size:smaller" + ";top:" + string.Concat(@control.TopLocation + @control.Height + 10, "px") + " ";
                    <div>
                        <label class="error hide" id="lbl_" @control.ControlId.ToString() style="@errorLabelStyle">This field is required.</label>
                    </div>
```

and changing their class to 'show' on button click or onblur events from JS.But if you see the first error label is getting hidden behind the second Input field(due to the top position of the second input field).

How can I fix this?Is it possible?(Specially when I don't have any control on the positions of the input fields)Any help will be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide sandbox demo that replicates problem so that we can see what the issue is.

Comment: there is no css in that fiddle

Comment: Please check this:http://jsfiddle.net/jchfxuhs/  Basically it has 2 cdns for Font-awesome and bootstrap css.

Comment: Why is there so much in line styling?

Comment: Why do you need all this absolute positioning for `input` elements in the first place? If you want absolute position for the error elements only make the parent wrapper position relative. This positioning logic you are using makes no sense

Comment: Eventhough I make the input fields position as relative and error label as absolute, still the error labels are coming behind the next input field based on the top-left positioning of the next element.

Comment: Can you please edit the jsfiddle and lemme know, atleast I am not able to make them as per your suggestion, may be I am missing something!

Comment: Use bootstrap grid to align the labels and inputs without position absolute. This whole thing is far more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: As I have mentioned these positioning of the labels and the input fields(height,width,top,left) are coming from DB and based on those metrics I am suppose to render them.I mean there can be 3-4 labels and input fields on the same line;do you think using bootstrap + default positions(as received from DB) can work together? Point is this design is not static, it is dynamic, there is a separate 'Designer' application (which I have no control over) which sets these values.

Comment: @charlietfl , can you pls edit the JSFiddle and gimme some idea?

Comment: need to work closely with the designer app then by using same  style baselines and making sure things align in that app properly. Garbage in equals garbage out

Comment: Hmm, that is out of scope for now, but thanks anyway for your time and suggestions and comments!